# Materialize select scrolling issue

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm working on a web app that uses a select with quite a number of options. The problem is some options cannot be seen on screen since MaterializeCSS' select does seem to be scrollable. How do I fix this?

[image]

HTML and PHP

```
<div class="main container">
<div class="section">
  ...
  ...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3">
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a degree program</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($degrees as $degree){
          echo '<option value="'.$degree.'">'.$degree.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
      </select>
      <label>Degree program</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `select{position:absolute}`

Comment: @Pugazh yes, but that did not have any effect

Comment: http://i.snag.gy/yYHNY.jpg - so materialize select IS scrollable our of box. In your place I would check it myself on their website, then try to find what and why I have differently and try to fix it

Comment: @mizurnix tried using firefox (using chrome before) and it worked. so this must be compatibility issue then? tried some random mobile browser, and it still had the same problem

Comment: So their examples also have the same problem on that browser? My screenshot was from Win 10 Chrome. I can confirm I have used those selects several times and they seem to work fine and have scrollbars cross-browser, including chrome on Android and at least some popular browser on iOS (don't know which but did not hear testers complain after testing on iPhone either)

Comment: @mizurnix Their examples do not have that many options, so as expected the scrollbar does not show. I'm also working on Win10 Chrome. It's not much of a big deal actually. It's okay even if I don't fix/solve it. What's frustrating is I don't even know what the problem is or where is it coming from.

Comment: http://i.snag.gy/umCxA.jpg. This is my implementation. I did change some stuff inside but only styles, the basic parts are default and scroll worked out of box, that's why I think you might have done something wrong. You should create a jsFiddle and maybe you can figure out what's wrong on your own while doing that. If not, then share that fiddle and we'll try to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     .select-dropdown{
        overflow-y: auto !important;
    }
```

Found this on another website so I can't claim credit. [Final comment on this page](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2592)

Answer (score 10):

Please you find `.dropdown-content` in materialize.css.

You see `max-height:650px` and remove/update it you want to dropdown box size.

I have been fixed this style in my project.
It is ok!. Thanks.....

Before removed/updated `max-height:650px` property in materialize.css
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtYBu.png)

```
.dropdown-content {
    max-height: 650px;
}
```

And I customize max-height:250px in materialize.css
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPlsu.png)

```
.dropdown-content {
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: May thanks, this solves the issue...there seems to be a singular problem when there are few options to chose from yet the drop-down UI is not completely visible.

Answer (score 8):

Neither of the above worked for me, but [this did](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2592#issuecomment-479462519).

```
.dropdown-content {
   max-height: 350px !important;
   overflow-y: auto !important;
   backface-visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same use-case on Materialize version (1.0.0).
I fixed it with the following.

```
.select-wrapper ul {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its causing your entire DOM to lock ( was for me ), add:

```
body { overflow: auto !important; }
```

For some reason calling AutoInit after a DOM change on select was adding overflow:hidden to the body tag.